# Android Bottom Sheet is not working in Fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment, kotlin-android

I have added the bottom sheet dialog on a fragment.
Right now I can't open it.
Whenever I click on the show button it doesn't work at all.
How can I fix this problem?

**CreateFragment.kt**

```
class CreateFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var binding: FragmentCreateBinding;
    val viewModel: NotesViewModel by viewModels()
    private var color = -1
    private val currentDate = SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().format(Date())
    private lateinit var result: String
    private val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentCreateBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        val animation = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
            drawingViewId = R.id.createFragment
            scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            duration = 300L
        }

        binding.backbutton.setOnClickListener {
            requireView().hideKeyboard()
            Navigation.findNavController(it).popBackStack()

        }

        sharedElementEnterTransition = animation
        sharedElementReturnTransition = animation

        binding.fabcolorpick.setOnClickListener {
            val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(
                requireContext(),
                R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme
            )
            val bottomSheetView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.bottomsheetlayout,
                null,
            )
            val bottomSheetBinding = BottomsheetlayoutBinding.bind(bottomSheetView)
            bottomSheetBinding.apply {
                colorpicker.apply {
                    setSelectedColor(color)
                    setOnColorSelectedListener { value ->
                        color = value
                        binding.apply {
                            createFragmentxmlid.setBackgroundColor(color)
                            toolbarfragmentnotecontent.setBackgroundColor(color)
                            bottombar.setBackgroundColor(color)
                            activity?.window?.statusBarColor = color
                        }
                        bottomSheetBinding.bottomSheetparent.setCardBackgroundColor(color)
                    }
                }
                bottomSheetparent.setCardBackgroundColor(color)
            }
            bottomSheetView.post {
                bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }

        }
        binding.btndonenotes.setOnClickListener {
            createNotes(it)
        }
        try {
            binding.edittextnote.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
                if (hasFocus) {
                    binding.bottombar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.edittextnote.setStylesBar(binding.styleBar)
                } else {
                    binding.bottombar.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            Log.d("TAG", e.stackTraceToString())
        }
        return binding.root
    }
```

Comment: You didn't `show()` on `bottomSheetDialog ` and didn't bind with `bottomSheetDialog'<-> `bottomSheetBinding`, it may used `bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetBinding.root)`

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would do it

- create the view
- set view as content of dialog
- call the dialog's show() method to show it or dismiss() method to dismiss it

```
// the content view
val bottomSheetView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.bottomsheetlayout,
                null,
            )
// and the dialog
val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog( requireContext(),R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme).apply{
        setContent(bottomSheetView)

        // or if I am using viewBinding
        setContent(bottomSheetBinding.root)
}

// then in button's onClick
button.setOnClickListener{
       bottomSheetDialog.show()
}
```